# Can you upcast in objective-c and how?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Can you upcast in objective-c?  if so how?

---

C# example:

"Asset" is the base class.

```
Stock msft = new Stock(); 
Asset a = msft;            //upcast
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean typecast a subclass object to the type of a superclass?  Sure - Objective-C has very liberal typecasting rules, just like C.

```
Superclass *superclassObject = (Superclass *)subclassObject;
```

Comment: You don't even need to explicitly cast going that direction

Comment: @cobbal - yeah, I'm not sure I understood the OP's question.  I just included the explicit cast for explicitness' sake. =)